# Difference between Decorator Pattern and Singleton Pattern

Tags: ruby, design-patterns, singleton, decorator

I'm trying to understand the difference between the Decorator and Singleton Pattern. For example, in Ruby if I wanted to implement a Singleton Pattern I can use the singleton class. But when I read about the Decorator Pattern in Wikipedia I feel like I would use a singleton class in that case as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Singleton pattern ensures that only one instance (or a limited number of instances) of a class exists at any given time. On the other hand, the Decorator pattern is a mechanism for dynamically adding functionality (responsibilities) to an object, by changing its "skin". Singleton is a creational pattern, whereas Decorator is a structural pattern.

There really isn't much in common between the two of them, what's the source of your confusion? Wait a bit before using  Ruby's Singleton module, better go straight to the original [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612) and understand the fundamental concepts, before thinking about implementation details.

Comment: I guess my lack of knowledge on the subject. When you say, "By changing its skin," can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Quoting the book: "We can think of a Decorator as a skin over an object that changes its behaviour. An alternative it's to change the object's guts. The Strategy pattern is a good example of a pattern for changing its guts"

Comment: Thanks for the quote and the book suggestion. I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

Decorator is an object wrapper which intentions is to enhance the behaviour of the subject object. The idea is that the decorator object can be used as a replacement for the wrapped object (must respect the protocol).